# How can I return columns from join while using group by clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, ssms

I am trying to return t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t1.city, t1.stateprovince, and I would like to return t2.amount, t2.restaurantname, t2.restaurantnum, t2.datekey, and t2.amount as well.

This is the code I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.[FirstName] AS FirstName,
    t1.[LastName] AS LastName,
    t1.[City] AS City,
    t1.[StateProvince] AS StateProvince
FROM 
    Database.dbo.CustomerData t1
JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         MAX(t2.[Amount]) AS Amount,
         MAX(t2.[Account]) AS Account,
         MAX(t2.[CardNumber]) AS CardNumber,
         MAX(t2.[RestaurantNum]) AS RestaurantNum,
         MAX(t2.[RestaurantName]) AS RestaurantName,
         MAX(t2.[DateKey]) AS DateKey,
         SUM([t2].[Amount]) AS Total_Spend
     FROM 
         gift.TransactionItems t2
     GROUP BY 
         t2.[Amount],
         t2.[RestaurantNum],
         t2.[RestaurantName],
         t2.[DateKey],
         t2.[AccountID],
         t2.[TransactionID]) t2 ON t1.[CardNumber] = t2.[CardNumber]
WHERE
    [FirstName] IS NOT NULL
    AND [LastName] IS NOT NULL
    AND [EmailFailed] IS NULL       
    AND [IsRegistered] = 'Yes'
    AND [DateKey] BETWEEN 20180601 AND 20181213
    AND t2.[Account] = 'Dollars_Spent_Accrued'
```

Is this possible? It currently only returns t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t1.city, and t1.stateprovince.

Answer (score 0):

If the query does not work when you add the columns then I would put the t2 query into a temp table then do the join and see if that works better. After a certain amount of complexity I usually opt for temp tables and break things out:

```
drop table if exists #t2
SELECT DISTINCT
         MAX(t2.[Amount]) AS Amount,
         MAX(t2.[Account]) AS Account,
         MAX(t2.[CardNumber]) AS CardNumber,
         MAX(t2.[RestaurantNum]) AS RestaurantNum,
         MAX(t2.[RestaurantName]) AS RestaurantName,
         MAX(t2.[DateKey]) AS DateKey,
         SUM([t2].[Amount]) AS Total_Spend
     INTO #t2 FROM 
         gift.TransactionItems t2
     GROUP BY 
         t2.[Amount],
         t2.[RestaurantNum],
         t2.[RestaurantName],
         t2.[DateKey],
         t2.[AccountID],
         t2.[TransactionID]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your query lists the values that will be returned. You had only listed the values from `t1`, despite the columns from `t2` being included in the FROM segment of your query. You need to explicitly add them the the SELECT segment of the query. Let me know if this works for you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.[FirstName] AS FirstName,
    t1.[LastName] AS LastName,
    t1.[City] AS City,
    t1.[StateProvince] AS StateProvince
    t2.[amount], 
    t2.[restaurantname], 
    t2.[restaurantnum], 
    t2.[datekey]
FROM 
    Database.dbo.CustomerData t1
JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         MAX(t2.[Amount]) AS Amount,
         MAX(t2.[Account]) AS Account,
         MAX(t2.[CardNumber]) AS CardNumber,
         MAX(t2.[RestaurantNum]) AS RestaurantNum,
         MAX(t2.[RestaurantName]) AS RestaurantName,
         MAX(t2.[DateKey]) AS DateKey,
         SUM([t2].[Amount]) AS Total_Spend
     FROM 
         gift.TransactionItems
     GROUP BY 
         t2.[Amount],
         t2.[RestaurantNum],
         t2.[RestaurantName],
         t2.[DateKey],
         t2.[AccountID],
         t2.[TransactionID]) t2 ON t1.[CardNumber] = t2.[CardNumber]
WHERE
    [FirstName] IS NOT NULL
    AND [LastName] IS NOT NULL
    AND [EmailFailed] IS NULL       
    AND [IsRegistered] = 'Yes'
    AND [DateKey] BETWEEN 20180601 AND 20181213
    AND t2.[Account] = 'Dollars_Spent_Accrued'
```

Comment: This does not work. Unfortunately, it won't recognize t1 values now.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: I think it's because t2 is referenced twice in your query, try taking out the first instance of it. I'll update my answer